# Sent message callback not responding string

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing an internal chrome devtools extension.

I have a panel which should show the URL of the page being debugged. And a background page.
here is part of the *panel.js* script :

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage( {'action':'get_url'}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        input.value = reponse;
    });
});
```

in my *background.js* script :

```
onRequest = function(request, sender, callback) {
    var url = 'default';
    if (request.action == 'get_url') {
       chrome.tabs.query({'active':true}, function(tabs) {
          url = tabs[0].url;
       });
       callback(url);
    }
};

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```

All I am getting is 'default' but in the debug tools I can see callback is called with the url I expected.

What am I missing ?
I am new to chrome extension development, any advice would be appreciate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thank you guys. I did search if my question was already asked but did not find any. Would you mind giving tips on how to do effective search ? for instance with my issue what did you type ?

Comment: If you know the answer, then it is easy to find the duplicate: `chrome extension onMessage return true` to find one of the many duplicates for one part of your question (via Google), and `chrome.tabs.query result not available` to find the other.